# STL vs Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++14

i know it's very silly question to ask. 
I am asking question as a beginner, as I am learning DsAlgo.

So let's take an example of simply rotating a sorted array.

There are two approaches I can follow.
1.STL
2.Without STL

I can simply do this by using `std::rotate` or I can use juggling algorithm. The Big-O complexity for both approaches is O(n).

So if I can simply make a code a two liner, why would I need to learn different algorithms?

I am really confused whether which way I should go with.

Comment: Once you mentioned STL, I strongly suggest you to go to http://stepanovpapers.com and read some papers written by the father of STL - Alexander Stepanov.

Answer (score 6):

If the standard library has algorithms that get your job done, **you should use them!** Here are a few reasons why:

1. It's simply there, you don't have to rewrite it.
2. It's thoroughly tested and much less likely to be buggy than something you rolled out yourself.
3. It's likely implemented by the same folks who wrote the compiler, so it's probably as optimized as possible. They also had more time to optimize that code.
4. It's more explicit and easy to understand for anyone who has to read your code later on.
5. When you switch to a newer/better compiler, your code could possibly be faster with no work on your side.

Comment: Very well jotted down @Ayxan

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can make your code 2 liner. That is how it should be. You should make use of **standard libraries** as they are written in the best possible manner with a lot factors taken into consideration.

Now, the question is, why should you learn algorithm:

Libraries provide abstract implementations. You don't know what's going behind the scene.

Some libraries are open source, through which you can learn best practices how to write codes as they are developed by the persons who write the compilers.

Now, if you want to implement any use case which demands a particular constraints on time and space complexity, you should know what is the algorithm, how it works and is that suitable for the use case.

By learning algorithms, you can also devise new algorithms for specific use cases, which are not found in standard libraries. Libraries just provide solutions to basic algorithms and not everything.

By learning algorithms, you can develop your own libraries and make it public so that other developers may use it to save time and build a robust code.

Comment: Some libraries (and some C or C++ compilers) are open source. With efforts, you can understand how they work.

Comment: Cool @BasileStarynkevitch, making the changes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thanks, that was important point. I request, if you have some more, kindly improve my answer.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire so is STL allowed in Interviews or competitive programming? STL always been my priority, today i wrote a binary search algorithm which had the same results and complexity as binary_search function in STL, so i am assuming, it's better to use STL wherever possible right? Would that affect interview?

Comment: It is always good to use STL. No issues with interview. But, if interviewer asks you about the working, you should know that